# Error filling print, Could not resolve style(s):{blank_style_name}

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with iReport, I am using iReport Designer 5.0.1.
It said that the iReport can not resolve styles, but it didn't tell which style is it. Only blank name after colon. And the most vague things is, the style is working in my other jrxml report files.

**This is my style codes:**

```
<style name="Kolom" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#757575" fill="Solid" vAlign="Middle" fontName="Serif" fontSize="12" isBold="false">
    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
        <pen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#616161"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#616161"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#616161"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#616161"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#616161"/>
    </box>
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
</style>
<style name="Baris" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#FFFFFF" fill="Solid" vAlign="Middle" fontName="Serif" fontSize="11" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false">
    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FF6666"/>
    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
        <pen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#CCCCFF"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#CCCCFF"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#CCCCFF"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#CCCCFF"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.55" lineColor="#CCCCFF"/>
    </box>
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
</style>
```

**And the iReport Output shows:**

```
    Error filling print... Could not resolve style(s):  
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not resolve style(s):       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.checkUnresolvedReferences(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1579)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.setStyles(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1506)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.loadStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:1005)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:879)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Comment: is your report working without using styles?

Comment: no, when i removed the styles,ireport output still showing the same vague error message

Comment: The same error just like what I post earlier. "Could not resolve style(s):  ????" It said that report could not resolve style, but it didn't tell us which style is it?

Answer (score 10):

Please look for this **style=""** in your jrxml file and delete all occurrences of those.

This worked for me. I hope it helps but let me know.

Good luck

Comment: Yeah, this Works.

Comment: {blank style name} or simple a dot. The error seems to be the same and this answer is correct and should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 3):

I received this error while copying "Table element" from another jrxml file.
Later identified that the style information should also be copied.

[image]

Please check if this resolves your issue.